# SQL filling missing date entries, and including previous date's counts

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as follows

| Date | Id | Group | Name | ScoreCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-20 | 1 | Athlete | Adam | 52 |
| 2022-06-23 | 1 | Athlete | Adam | 77 |
| 2022-06-25 | 1 | Athlete | Adam | 79 |
| 2022-06-19 | 1 | Employee | Adam | 65 |
| 2022-06-22 | 1 | Employee | Adam | 28 |

I'd like this for the dates to be added for each individual id and type of group. So it should look something like:

| Date | Id | Group | Name | ScoreCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-20 | 1 | Athlete | Adam | 52 |
| 2022-06-21 | 1 | Athlete | Adam | 52 |
| 2022-06-22 | 1 | Athlete | Adam | 52 |
| 2022-06-23 | 1 | Athlete | Adam | 77 |
| 2022-06-24 | 1 | Athlete | Adam | 77 |
| 2022-06-25 | 1 | Athlete | Adam | 79 |
| 2022-06-19 | 1 | Employee | Adam | 65 |
| 2022-06-20 | 1 | Employee | Adam | 65 |
| 2022-06-21 | 1 | Employee | Adam | 65 |
| 2022-06-22 | 1 | Employee | Adam | 28 |

My code is as follows:

```
WITH t as (SELECT
Id,
Group,
Name,
min(Date) as MinDate
max(Date) as MaxDate
FROM recordTable
GROUP BY Id,Group,Name

SELECT t.Id,
 t.Group,
 t.Name,
 c.Days,
 (SELECT LAST_VALUE(ScoreCount) FROM recordTable WHERE t.Id = recordTable.Id AND t.Group = recordTable.Group)
FROM t
LEFT JOIN calendar c ON c.Days BETWEEN t.MinDate AND t.MaxDate
```

calendar is the table that contains individual dates for the year 2022, so they can be joined. Everything works, except for the ScoreCount, which Last_Value isn't actually doing what I want it to do. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try reversing the table join order as `FROM calendar LEFT JOIN t`

Comment: @AnkitBajpai if I do that then it won't include the scorecount

Comment: Scorecount is in inline sub-query, While you need to reverse your order in your final query.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai could you provide an example of what you mean? I'm trying to only have the missing dates, and my join isn't matching correctly

Answer (score 1):

You can simply try reversing the order of your joined tables -

```
WITH t as (SELECT Id,
                  Group,
                  Name,
                  min(Date) as MinDate,
                  max(Date) as MaxDate
             FROM recordTable
            GROUP BY Id,Group,Name
          )
SELECT t.Id,
       t.Group,
       t.Name,
       c.Days,
       (SELECT LAST_VALUE(ScoreCount) OVER(<your over clause is missing>)
          FROM recordTable 
         WHERE t.Id = recordTable.Id
           AND t.Group = recordTable.Group)
  FROM calendar c
  LEFT JOIN t ON c.Days BETWEEN t.MinDate AND t.MaxDate
```

Although I have not tested the query yet this will give you an idea to proceed further.

Comment: Thank you, I have not user over before, is this like range? For example the range of dates

Comment: OVER is used with all window functions. Just google about it. You will get a lot of information.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `last_value`, you can get the first value

```
WITH t as (
SELECT
[Id],
[Group],
[Name],
min([Date]) as MinDate,
max([Date]) as MaxDate
FROM recordTable
GROUP BY [Id],[Group],[Name]
)

SELECT 
 t.Id,
 t.[Group],
 t.[Name],
 c.[Date],
 (SELECT top 1 ScoreCount 
        from recordTable x 
        where x.[Date] <= c.[Days]
        and  x.[Group] = t.[Group] 
        and x.[Name] = t.[Name]
        order by x.[Date] desc
) ScoreCount
FROM t
LEFT JOIN calendar c ON c.[Days] BETWEEN t.MinDate AND t.MaxDate
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across post since I had a similar issue.  The only difference is that I needed to get multiple values to be filled.  I dont think either of the solutions work for me since I would need multiple selects.

This is what I came up with using rownumber

```
with CTE as 
(
   Select
      c.days Date,
      r.Id,
      r.Group,
      r.Name,
      r.ScoreCount,
      rn = row_number() over ( Partition by r.Id, c.days ORDER BY r.Date
   FROM calendar c
   LEFT JOIN recordTable r on r.Date <= c.days
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE rn = 1
```